# How can I extract data from Netsuite to any database without using SuiteAnalytics

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

How can I extract data from Netsuite to any database without using SuiteAnalytics or without any paid feature

Comment: You can export certain types of data to a CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either push data from NetSuite to external database or pull data from your application into your database.

1. To push data from NetSuite into any database, you can try to write Schedule script. Schedule script should read required data from NetSuite and update the external database.
2. Another way is to call NetSuite's native APIs or custom RESTlet from your application. In this case, your application can read data from NetSuite and update any database.

Hope this answers helps you to move in right direction.